# Light weight frontend localization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internationalization, frontend

I have a simple landing page supporting 3 different languages. 
It looks like:

```
domain.com - English version (index.html)
domain.com/fr - (copy of index.html, but translated)
domain.com/de
```

So I need to edit HTML and texts several times per month, usually, I changed HTML code in English version, then copied the code to the other versions. The same with texts. 
It's waste of time.

I tried to use dom-i18n, but I need to keep these /de /fr links (I need to attach link with specific language in email promotion)

Do you have any suggestions about how can I organize this process better? Thank you!

Comment: You should google CMS ;)